# NPOI Excel File invalid file format or extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npoi

I'm trying to create an Endpoint in .NET Core 6 that should return a Excel File. The Problem is, that when i try to open the Excel File, it says the file format or extension is not valid.

That's my code:

### Controller

```
[HttpPost("/api/report")]
public async Task ExportFile([FromBody] ReportDTO reportDTO)
{
    _excelService.GenerateReport(HttpContext, reportDTO);
}
```

### Service

```
public void GenerateReport(HttpContext httpContext, ReportDTO reportDTO)
{
    IWorkbook workbook;
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Test");

    IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Test");
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Hello");

    row = excelSheet.CreateRow(1);
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(1);
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("World");

    workbook.WriteExcelToResponse(httpContext, GetFileName(reportDTO));
}
```

### Extension Method

```
public static void WriteExcelToResponse(this IWorkbook book, HttpContext httpContext, string templateName)
{
    var response = httpContext.Response;
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateName))
    {
        var contentDisposition = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        contentDisposition.SetHttpFileName(templateName);
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = contentDisposition.ToString();
    }
    book.Write(response.Body);
}
```

Comment: `application/vnd.ms-excel` is the content type for the obsolete `xls` format that was replace with `xlsx` in 2007. Use `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` instead and ensure the extension is `.xlsx`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet now but i'm still getting the same error. The File ends with .xlsx

Comment: Whats werid is that the downloaded files all have a size of 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could directly use memory stream and use Fileresult to return the Excel file.

More details, you could refer to below example:

```
    [HttpPost("/api/report")]
    public ActionResult ExportFile(/*[FromBody] ReportDTO reportDTO*/)
    {
        IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Test");

        IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);
        row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Test");
        row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Hello");

        row = excelSheet.CreateRow(1);
        row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(1);
        row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("World");


        using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.Write(exportData);
            string saveAsFileName = string.Format("Export-{0:d}.xlsx", DateTime.Now).Replace("/", "-");
            byte[] bytes = exportData.ToArray();
            return File(bytes, "application/vnd.ms-excel", saveAsFileName);
        }

    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The `return File(bytes, ...)` only works in the controller, so i just passed the controller as a parameter to the Service.

Comment: If you feel my reply has helped you, please mark it as answer. This will help other folks who faced the same issue to find the issue more easily.  Thank you very much,.